# what is translate=“label” in xml file what it does?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I am working with Magento XML files and I found

`translate=" label"`

```
 <tabs>
     <training translate="label" module="training">
         <label>training</label>
         <sort_order>50</sort_order>
     </training>
 </tabs>
```

I want to know how it works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550429/about-translate-label-attribute-in-magento-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A workaround would be **to use the translate attribute to tell which
>   other attributes to translate.**

```
<tabs>
     <training translate="label" module="training">
         <label>training</label>
         <sort_order>50</sort_order>
     </training>
 </tabs>
```

---

In your example  `translate="label"` **where label is a
attribute** and it will translate the value of `<label>training</label>`

---

**More Explanation**

---

- Magento present the user interface in different languages without
  modifying the actual application source code. it translates the
  `system messages`, `error messages`, and `labels` for display in the
  `UI`.
- Some messages may be displayed in logs for a system administrator or
  a developer—those don't need to be translated.
- By convention, in the source code, the labels and system messages for
  UI are expressed in English (en_US).
- In order to replace these phrases with alternatives in different
  languages when the source code is interpreted, **Magento has a layer
  of indirection.**

> In XML files, the conventional **translate** and **module** attributes
>   indicate that the contents of a node must be translated:

```
<tabs>
     <training translate="label" module="training">
         <label>training</label>
         <sort_order>50</sort_order>
     </training>
 </tabs>
```

The translate indicates a **child node** `that contains the phrase`, and "module" indicates context of a module.

Context indicates a kind of namespace for this phrase.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what is this used for.

Comment: Anytime :) Happy coding !